# if condition using telnet in perl not working

Tags: perl

I'm trying to use if condition to check if command has passed, but its not working. Even though the mount has been successful it goes to failed message. When i enter this command, it retruns to the prompt without any message, hence i'm comparing with a "". And when i do a "ls" of destination folder, it shows all contents of source folder. Any help? Is my if condition correct?

```
my $port  = new Net::Telnet->new(Host=>$ip,Port=>$ip_port,Timeout => "$timeout", Dump_Log => "dumplog.log",  Errmode=> "return" );
if($port->cmd("mount -t nfs -o nolock <path-of-source-folder> <destination-folder>") eq "")
{
        print "Successful\n";
}
else{
        print "Failed.\n ";
}
```

Comment: you call `new` twice.

Comment: port connection is sucessful. No worrries regarding that.

Comment: The problem was already pointed out in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23886656/logs-in-new-telnet-session-empty-in-perl -- if you want us to look at your code, please fix obvious problems first, if only to focus discussion to your actual topic.

Answer (score 1):

In scalar context, the Net::Telnet `cmd` method returns 1 on success (not a string). Your check should be something like:

```
if ($port->cmd("mount -t nfs -o nolock <path-of-source-folder> <destination-folder>") == 1)
{
    print "Successful\n";
} else {
    print "Failed.\n";
}
```

If you actually want to collect the output from the `mount` command and inspect it, you will have to either call it in list context or pass a stringref argument, like so:

```
my @outlines = $port->cmd("mount ...");
```

Or:

```
my $out;
my $ret = $port->cmd("mount ...", [Output => \$out]);
if ($ret == 1)
{
    # inspect $out
}
```

See the [Net::Telnet documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net%3a%3aTelnet) for more.

Answer (score 0):

Your check for the result seems to be wrong. The documenation of [Net::Telnet](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aTelnet#cmd---issue-command-and-retrieve-output) says that

> This method sends the command $string, and reads the characters sent back by the command up until and including the matching prompt. It's assumed that the program to which you're sending is some kind of command prompting interpreter such as a shell.
>   The command $string is automatically appended with the output_record_separator, by default it is "\n". This is similar to someone typing a command and hitting the return key. Set the output_record_separator to change this behavior.
>
> In a scalar context, the characters read from the remote side are discarded and 1 is returned on success.

So you need to check in a scalar context

```
if ($port->cmd("..") ) {
    ...
}
```